# Sharing multiple photos in WhatsApp

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, photos, sharing

How to share multiple photo in WhatsApp? I'm using a Lumia 730, and when I select multiple photos then WhatsApp is not in the share list, but if I select only one image then WhatsApp is there.

Answer (score 2):

You can share multiple photos in WhatsApp as follows:

1. Open WhatsApp
2. Select the person with whom you want to share photos
3. Tap the "attach" icon
4. In "Attach media", tap "Photo" and select the album where the photos are
5. Tap "select" at the bottom to mark the photos which you want to share

Note: You can share a maximum of 10 photos at once).

Answer (score 0):

This is something that WhatsApp has to support - therefore you should contact the Whatsapp developers directly to request this feature.